# Why is `str` a primitive type?

Tags: rust, internals

Looking at both the docs and the code, it appears that `str` is a primitive type, while `String` is a `struct { Vec<u8> }`. Now as `str` is to a `[u8]` what `String` is to a `Vec<u8>`, couldn't `str` have been defined as

```
struct str { slice: [u8]; }
```

similar to how AsciiStr is defined? Why was/is it (still?) defined as primitive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once dynamically sized types came along, there no longer remained any good reason for `str` to be a primitive type; it could entirely reasonably have become a structure as you indicate, with a lang item for the benefit of string literals. But there didn’t seem any especially good reason to change it either (though the possibility was discussed a few times), and so the status quo remained.

Comment: Ah, I thought that it was due to the current solution being good enough. Still it seemed a bit off, as in many places the language was reduced by moving constructs into std, that's why I asked.

Comment: See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19036 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19612

Comment: String literals *and* pattern matching!